$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{2+\cos^2x}=\int\frac{\sec²x}{\sec^2x(2+\cos^2x)}\,\mathrm dx$ But how?
This question came to me:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{2+\cos^2x}$$
and when I tried to solve I wasn't able to solve it, so I looked the solution and in that there was a step in which it was written:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{2+\cos^2x}=\int\frac{\sec²x}{\sec^2x(2+\cos^2x)}\,\mathrm dx$$
But domain of $f(x) =\frac{1}{2+\cos^2x}$ and domain of $f(x) =\frac{\sec^2x}{\sec^2x(2+\cos^2x)}$ are different and according to the definition of indefinite integral:
$$\int\frac{1}{2+\cos^2x}\,\mathrm dx= F(x) + c$$
such that
$$F^\prime(x) =  \frac{1}{1+2\cos^2x}$$
for all $x$ in the domain of $f(x) =1/(2+\cos^2x)$.
Now, from solving like this, we get
$$\int \frac{1}{2+\cos^2x}\,\mathrm dx =\int\frac{\sec^2x}{\sec^2x(2+\cos^2x)}\,\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt6}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt2\tan x}{\sqrt3}\right)+c$$
But
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt2\tan x}{\sqrt3}\right)+c$$
Then, $F^\prime(x) \neq 1/(2+\cos^2x)$ for $x = \pi/2$. Can someone explain?

Welcome to MSE! Take a look at MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference on how to format and display your mathematical expressions using MathJax to make your question more readable.

The title seems to be different from the question body

is it plus or minus? Regardless, you've multiplied integrand by $1$

Thanks, everyone for spending your time with this doubt. I was actually mistaken in understanding the concept.

Whilst the function may not technically be continuous (I believe) it is a removable discontinuity which you can integrate over

If $$
F(x)=\frac1{\sqrt6}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt2\tan x}{\sqrt3}\right)
$$
then the derivative of the function is:
$$F'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt6}\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\sec^2x\frac1{1+\frac{2\tan^2x}{3}}$$
$$F'(x)=\frac13\frac{3\sec^2x}{3+2\tan^2x}=\frac{\sec^2x}{3+2\tan^2x}$$
$$
=\frac{\sec^2x}{3+2(\sec^2x-1)}=\frac{\sec^2x}{1+2\sec^2x}=\frac{\sec^2x}{\sec^2x(2+\cos^2x)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2+\cos^2x}$$
I see that $F'(x)=\frac{1}{2+\cos^2x}$, then what's your problem? Add a comment and let me help.
Note: Regarding the case for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the function $F(x)$ is indeed undefined at that point. It has a discontinuity there, since
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}^+}F(x)$ is not the same as  $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}^-}F(x)$. But the domain of a function and its integral can surely differ.

Yup, I just misunderstood the definition of indefinite integral. I thought
$\int f(x) = F(x)$ if F'(x) = f(x) for all x belonging to domain of f.
But I realised it is actually, $\int f(x) = F(x)$ if F'(x) = f(x) for all x belonging to the domain of F.
Thanks for your response

I actually disagree with this answer, which is why I added my own. My issue is with the last paragraph: “But the domain of a function and its integral can surely differ.” The integrand in question is a continuous function on the whole real line, and by the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus, its antiderivative exists and is continuous on the whole real line. The discontinuities of the $F$ given by OP are real issues that need to be dealt with, and not to be ignored.

For integrals we usually care mostly about what happens on intervals, and little about what happens at isolated points. That is to say, the new discontinuity introduced by $(\sec(x))^2$ are only $\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$ where $k$ is integer (same below), and it doesn't introduce much trouble, and the solution gotten from it is still massively helpful. There just needs to be some minor tweaks afterwards, to deal with the new discontinuities. My solution to the indefinite integral is slightly more complicated than what you have given: it's
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\tan(x)\right)+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}\operatorname{round}\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right) + C,$$
with values at $\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$ are taken to be the limit, since all the discontinuities at $\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$ are removable. See this Desmos graph. You can manually write out the values at $\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$ and write $F(x)$ as a piecewise function; I'm just being lazy here. The idea is, your solution is a piecewise continuous function, with discontinuities at $\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$, so I add an appropriate constant ($\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}\operatorname{round}\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)$) to each piece so that the pieces join up at the discontinuities. As you can see, this solution's domain is the entire real line, agreeing with that of the integrand. It is also differentiable everywhere, whose derivative is exactly $\frac{1}{2+(\cos(x))^2}$.

Thanks for your response.
Actually, I just misunderstood the definition of indefinite integral. I thought ∫f(x)=F(x)
if F'(x) = f(x) for all x belonging to domain of f. But I realised it is actually, ∫f(x)=F(x)
if F'(x) = f(x) for all x belonging to the domain of F.
Btw, what is the meaning of that round?

@Curious. It’s the rounding function, returning the nearest integer to its input.
